# No keyword with name 'RowCnt' found

Tags: python, testing, error-handling, robotframework, keyword

hi im new to robot framework while executing this code am getting this error.

Fetch Records From Database Python
[Arguments]     ${strQuery}

```
# Step Check Query for empty or NUll
Should Be True  '$strQuery'    msg="Query can not be Empty.. Please provide the Query"

# Execute the Query and Get the Rowcount
${Execution Status}    ${RowCnt}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error            Row Count              ${strQuery}
Run Keyword If    "${Execution Status}" == "PASS"    info   Row Count for the given Query :- is ${strQuery} and Row Count is: - ${RowCnt}   ELSE    Fail    Error encountered while Querying the Database using Query -  ${strQuery}  and error is ${RowCnt}

#Verify Number of Records retrieved from DB
Run Keyword If    "${RowCnt}">= 1    info     Records returned from DB are either 1 or more than 1:- ${RowCnt}      ELSE    Fail    Record returned from DB is 0 and RowCnt is  -  ${RowCnt}. Refine the query and re-execute it
```

Comment: is this python code?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: in code you have `RowCnt` but in error `RowCount` - maybe you runs differnt code

Comment: this is my full code

Comment: Do you have DatabaseLibrary imported?

Comment: Yes I have imported.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a keyword named `RowCount` in DatabaseLibrary
Try replacing with `Row Count`

```
${Execution Status}  ${RowCnt}  Run Keyword And Ignore Error  Row Count  ${strQuery}
```

Comment: I have modified the code like you said. now am getting this error. "${RowCnt} = No keyword with name 'Row Count' found."

Comment: # Execute the Query and Get the Rowcount
 ${Execution Status}    ${RowCnt}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error RowCount ${strQuery}   
 Run Keyword If    "${Execution Status}"=="PASS"    info Row Cnt for the given Query :- is ${strQuery} and rowcnt is: - ${RowCnt} ELSE    Fail    Error encountered while Querying the Database using Query -  ${strQuery}  and error is ${RowCnt}

Comment: Hi Ramesh, "Row Count" keyword is in DatabaseLibrary, if it still isn't detected then it sounds like either it's not installed or you're not referencing the Library under settings section

Comment: I have added DatabaseLibrary and Installed still facing the same error.

Comment: Please add the full error information

Comment: Full Error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor' 
${Execution Status} = FAIL 
${RowCnt} = AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
@matthew-king